# How to inject custom test method parameters in TestNG

Tags: testing, testng

I need a way to inject a custom parameter into TestNG's test methods. **The parameter is my own object constructed dynamically at runtime from test method annotations**. The custom parameter is not known to TestNG, it's my own type, e.g.:

```
@com.mypackage.MyAnnotation("someValue)"
@org.testng.Test
public void test(MyCustomObject val) {
    ...
}
```

I need to most likely use some TestNG's listener, but I cannot find out which one.

**I don't want to use `@DataProvider`** annotation.

Comment: You can use data provider or Parameters annotation.

Comment: I will rewrite the question, this is not what I need.

Comment: define custom parameter...

Comment: Any kind of object, not known to TestNG.